# Remove all decimals from a string except the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove all the decimals in a string except for the last one in jQuery or JavaScript?

#### Original strings

```
1.233.543.00
456.00
1.234.00
```

#### Desired results

```
1233543.00
456.00
1234.00
```

My jQuery code to extract the values:

```
jQuery('.addui-slider-handle-l span').text()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this using this on the string:

```
.replace(/[.](?=.*[.])/g, "");
```

Comment: or `.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, "");`

Comment: So the big question: What is better? ;D

Comment: [.] and \. are same :D There is no better.

Comment: well you might say @NinaScholz is better only because it's 2 less characters of code.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Hard ;D Thanks to both of you guys. Works awesome now!

Answer (score 1):

```
function text(string){

var arrayDots=string.split(".")

var lastPart= arrayDots[arrayDots.length-1];

    var subresult="";

    for(var i=0; i<arrayDots.length-1; i++){
       subresult=subresult+arrayDots[i]; 
    }
     var result= subresult+"."+lastPart;

    console.log(result);
}
```

This is not the easiest way but you can get the logic

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's more efficient than the pure regex solution presented, but I know in general a lot of people are shy around regex, so here is a non-regex alternative.

Logic is to split the string at the dots, insert the last dot back in, and then join back to a string.

```
var x = "1.233.543.00".split('.');
x.length>1 && x.splice(-1,0,'.');
x = x.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can run this in a console on this page and get what you want for fun

```
$('#question').find('code').text().split(/\s/).slice(0,3).map(n => n.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, ""))
```